# Spacing Issue with Microsoft Equation Editor in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I'm using Microsoft Equation Editor for an equation, say: X=A/B

The numerator has the phrase "Consideration amount from Report". When I click outside the equation after typing, the word "consideration" appears as "consideration", with an unwanted space appearing after the word's first 10 characters.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this here, but can you post a document that shows the problem somewhere, e.g. Dropbox?